# getopts use special characters as arguments

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I was wondering if I could write my script in a way that getopts will accept special characters as arguments.

This is what I have:

```
File=0;

while getopts "<:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    <) File=$(echo $OPTARG)
      ;;
    \?) echo "Syntax error"
        exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

The problem is this is giving me the following error:

[image: unix getotps error]

Can anyone please help me fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you quote it (both in the script and on the command line):

```
while getopts "<:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    "<") File=$(echo $OPTARG)
      ;;
    \?) echo "Syntax error"
        exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

Call the script like this:

```
$ ./test.sh "-<" test
```

Comment: but it's not possible to do it without qouting on the command line?

Comment: It kindoff needs to work so my script will accept stdin and still run so script.sh < file should work

Comment: @Joey: No, `<` will mean stdin redirection if not quoted.

Comment: Is there a way to make my script work with < (doesn't have to be getopts)

Comment: @Joey: you need to provide more details on how you're calling the script, what error you're getting, etc. It may be better to ask a new question.

Comment: @joey: In Unix, you don't have to worry about handling `< file`. The shell will deal with that for you, by redirecting stdin to the file. Your utility doesn't even see the redirection.